# power bi and azure Table live refresh

Tags: azure-table-storage, powerbi

i have a question, can we do a live refresh of our data source on power BI ?
my data source is azure Table Storage . and when the data changes , i have to click the update data button to get the new results on my dash board .

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Power BI pro you can have your data automatically refresh up to 8 times per day.  The only way to accomplish viewing "live" data in power bi would be to use "Direct Query" mode which does not seem to support Azure Table storage.

More information on refreshing data can be found [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-refresh-data/#live-connections-and-directquery-to-on-premises-data-sources) and [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?q=direct%20query).